# Writing to specific location of .txt using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Can anyone please let me know how to write to a notepad file which has multiple contents, and I need to write the output to a particular place.

Say for ex:- I have a notepad with contents

```
System Name=abc123_1223
System_Ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
Domain_Name= ??
```

Now I need to update the domain name which I can get from

```
Set Info = CreateObject("AdSystemInfo")
GetDomainName = Info.DomainDNSName
```

is there a way?

Comment: Please give an example of how your file looks before and after you have modified it. Do this by clicking `edit` and adding it to your question, not by adding a comment because the formatting is difficult in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the content of the file into a variable:

```
data = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt").ReadAll
```

replace the line with a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "^(Domain_Name=).*"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.MultiLine  = True

data = re.Replace(data, "$1" & Info.DomainDNSName)
```

then write the modified data back to the file:

```
fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt", 2).Write data
```